# Polyline Static Map URL character error

Tags: google-maps, url, static, polyline, google-maps-static-api

I am trying to get a polyline map using a static map URL. My problem is that looks like a character (maybe ^) is not helping me to produce the map and it shows the global map. 
This is my polyline:

mzxnEfswpUQVmCoCmAgAiDsD??GNUS_HqGeC}B{AuAy@u@oCcD??KPUSoBiBMMIG}EoEtBmC??SQNYP]jCuEhCuE{I{I??IL_@_@kF_FMIOOUSSUIG[WgB_BYWk@}@??IJ_A{@WWOOc@]BW@W@gAAq@C_C?e@@[Fo@@KBQJo@t@qA??WKDW^mB`AaFVsAHc@RgAJc@Nw@Fc@rAcE??YKJo@z@qEbByGdCgJJc@BIRg@v@_Cn@cBX_AYcC??WLaBmFY{@q@qBO[i@sAUm@Se@IYuA_GBiA??WJyAiGmEwGeBgC[c@[mA??QTQWmDuEe@o@KM_@e@YkA??QTY_@w@aASsA??SRQ[s@wA{@wAeDaH??SPYa@mAoB_EcGcA}AGKe@s@S]OQ_@s@o@qA_@}@KYGoA??UNcAmCIsA??UNiA}CgBcFwBwH??UN_BeEQe@Wo@O[_@k@Y]KK{@u@W[aE_ESOKKSo@??KXm@_@[WuK{GyBuB??KXq@_@aKgGmBkB??KXWOgBeAe@Su@u@g@e@k@g@KGMKq@a@UMa@G{@EqDM[CY?QESIOEc@SQKc@]g@e@k@kA??OXUSu@k@wBoBaByAiAmAyAyAeEuDg@e@[_@MOU]QYOW{@qBMYI[Li@??WLKe@Ga@I_@Gs@C[Ck@EqBAm@?sABw@FkBFy@Fm@Dq@T_B^mD`AkBBMZ}@??SCB_@?Q?o@Ew@Ca@CWGa@GWG]Qi@IUUa@EMKQGIWiB??QJSg@{BuGcCaK??UNMa@aDcK]cC??UJK]iAkDGUE[MgARk@??YDkAsS??WDC_@KeAKuAK_AKc@q@{BSk@Fc@??QPS]S]kIgNiB}C}@}A_@_B??SRIKqBiD_BkCq@*Ag@o@k@k@w@eAS[uBmD{@yA[c@QS[]Mm@??GX]S*@Qm@WSEYKg@Mg@Gg@AkAAe@]???\w@?oLi@??l@^m@ASAOAUAa@ISEa@Mu@Yq@]q@a@WQ][i@m@k@w@Q_@IM[*AQc@Ke@SgAGo@T[??YDE*@Aw@AgCAkDCuEXk@??Y?AaE?}A?wCVo@??W?A}AAmD?oFTkI??Wn@?o@?cE?{DAm@EmAC_@CWS{AGSOk@Yu@]}@Fi@??UPM[sDeH}BwE{@gBAw@??UPa@}@qB}Do@uA_@m@}@cB}AoC]aB??SPeAkBmA{Bq@gAaFcK??Bv@Wc@}B}DsC{EgAmBsA_CsDmGk@aAaCmE_@aB??SRGKOUKSoAoBaA{Aw@wAk@eAg@eA[}@iA}DB_A??WLmAcFaAqDkCkJwAmFDy@??UJeA_Eq@iCYgAqBmHgDeO???fAU{@uAgFsB}Hq@gCsB{Hi@sBB{@??UJUy@Mg@w@mC}AoG{@oDWgAF{@??UJ]yAQaA{@qEUmAi@cCUqAG[WmAK[Ia@Ma@g@qAOg@IYKa@Pe@??YJQ_Ak@uCk@gDUkAOs@?wA??WJOu@CIu@kD[aBw@{DOu@Rc@??YHIi@Im@MkAMiAO}ASsCEk@UcDC]Gq@@oG??WDCw@KoCCQKaCQcC_@{EWyCIkAEq@?sG??Ul@Ck@Au@UiI}@_i@??UbACaAa@yY??Ur@Aq@a@yM]yW??SbAEaAGoBKeCAeB@yAHmED_DKs@ISQUIGa@E{AC_@Em@|D

If I insert my polyline in a website like this, it works:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

But when I try to create my static URL is not working. This is my link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=900x900&path=weight:5%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:mzxnEfswpUQVmCoCmAgAiDsD??GNUS_HqGeC}B{AuAy@u@oCcD??KPUSoBiBMMIG}EoEtBmC??SQNYP]jCuEhCuE{I{I??IL_@_@kF_FMIOOUSSUIG[WgB_BYWk@}@??IJ_A{@WWOOc@]BW@W@gAAq@C_C?e@@[Fo@@KBQJo@t@qA??WKDW^mB`AaFVsAHc@RgAJc@Nw@Fc@rAcE??YKJo@z@qEbByGdCgJJc@BIRg@v@_Cn@cBX_AYcC??WLaBmFY{@q@qBO[i@sAUm@Se@IYuA_GBiA??WJyAiGmEwGeBgC[c@[mA??QTQWmDuEe@o@KM_@e@YkA??QTY_@w@aASsA??SRQ[s@wA{@wAeDaH??SPYa@mAoB_EcGcA}AGKe@s@S]OQ_@s@o@qA_@}@KYGoA??UNcAmCIsA??UNiA}CgBcFwBwH??UN_BeEQe@Wo@O[_@k@Y]KK{@u@W[aE_ESOKKSo@??KXm@_@[WuK{GyBuB??KXq@_@aKgGmBkB??KXWOgBeAe@Su@u@g@e@k@g@KGMKq@a@UMa@G{@EqDM[CY?QESIOEc@SQKc@]g@e@k@kA??OXUSu@k@wBoBaByAiAmAyAyAeEuDg@e@[_@MOU]QYOW{@qBMYI[Li@??WLKe@Ga@I_@Gs@C[Ck@EqBAm@?sABw@FkBFy@Fm@Dq@T_B^mD`AkBBMZ}@??SCB_@?Q?o@Ew@Ca@CWGa@GWG]Qi@IUUa@EMKQGIWiB??QJSg@{BuGcCaK??UNMa@aDcK]cC??UJK]iAkDGUE[MgARk@??YDkAsS??WDC_@KeAKuAK_AKc@q@{BSk@Fc@??QPS]S]kIgNiB}C}@}A_@_B??SRIKqBiD_BkCq@*Ag@o@k@k@w@eAS[uBmD{@yA[c@QS[]Mm@??GX]S*@Qm@WSEYKg@Mg@Gg@AkAAe@]???\w@?oLi@??l@^m@ASAOAUAa@ISEa@Mu@Yq@]q@a@WQ][i@m@k@w@Q_@IM[*AQc@Ke@SgAGo@T[??YDE*@Aw@AgCAkDCuEXk@??Y?AaE?}A?wCVo@??W?A}AAmD?oFTkI??Wn@?o@?cE?{DAm@EmAC_@CWS{AGSOk@Yu@]}@Fi@??UPM[sDeH}BwE{@gBAw@??UPa@}@qB}Do@uA_@m@}@cB}AoC]aB??SPeAkBmA{Bq@gAaFcK??Bv@Wc@}B}DsC{EgAmBsA_CsDmGk@aAaCmE_@aB??SRGKOUKSoAoBaA{Aw@wAk@eAg@eA[}@iA}DB_A??WLmAcFaAqDkCkJwAmFDy@??UJeA_Eq@iCYgAqBmHgDeO???fAU{@uAgFsB}Hq@gCsB{Hi@sBB{@??UJUy@Mg@w@mC}AoG{@oDWgAF{@??UJ]yAQaA{@qEUmAi@cCUqAG[WmAK[Ia@Ma@g@qAOg@IYKa@Pe@??YJQ_Ak@uCk@gDUkAOs@?wA??WJOu@CIu@kD[aBw@{DOu@Rc@??YHIi@Im@MkAMiAO}ASsCEk@UcDC]Gq@@oG??WDCw@KoCCQKaCQcC_@{EWyCIkAEq@?sG??Ul@Ck@Au@UiI}@_i@??UbACaAa@yY??Ur@Aq@a@yM]yW??SbAEaAGoBKeCAeB@yAHmED_DKs@ISQUIGa@E{AC_@Em@|D

If I slightly modify the first ^ for a random letter as an "m" it works, but that change the coordinates that I am searching. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Note that in polyline we don't need the center and zoom as it is described in the documentation google developers static-maps documentation.

This is my first post in here, so I will really appreciate your help!

Comment: By the way, looks like this edito is changing my ` for a white space. You can notice that because my polyline change to grey.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there is a `@` missing at the end of the encoded polyline

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=900x900&path=weight:5|color:0x000000ff|enc:mzxnEfswpUQVmCoCmAgAiDsD??GNUS_HqGeC}B{AuAy@u@oCcD??KPUSoBiBMMIG}EoEtBmC??SQNYP]jCuEhCuE{I{I??IL_@_@kF_FMIOOUSSUIG[WgB_BYWk@}@??IJ_A{@WWOOc@]BW@W@gAAq@C_C?e@@[Fo@@KBQJo@t@qA??WKDW^mB`AaFVsAHc@RgAJc@Nw@Fc@rAcE??YKJo@z@qEbByGdCgJJc@BIRg@v@_Cn@cBX_AYcC??WLaBmFY{@q@qBO[i@sAUm@Se@IYuA_GBiA??WJyAiGmEwGeBgC[c@[mA??QTQWmDuEe@o@KM_@e@YkA??QTY_@w@aASsA??SRQ[s@wA{@wAeDaH??SPYa@mAoB_EcGcA}AGKe@s@S]OQ_@s@o@qA_@}@KYGoA??UNcAmCIsA??UNiA}CgBcFwBwH??UN_BeEQe@Wo@O[_@k@Y]KK{@u@W[aE_ESOKKSo@??KXm@_@[WuK{GyBuB??KXq@_@aKgGmBkB??KXWOgBeAe@Su@u@g@e@k@g@KGMKq@a@UMa@G{@EqDM[CY?QESIOEc@SQKc@]g@e@k@kA??OXUSu@k@wBoBaByAiAmAyAyAeEuDg@e@[_@MOU]QYOW{@qBMYI[Li@??WLKe@Ga@I_@Gs@C[Ck@EqBAm@?sABw@FkBFy@Fm@Dq@T_B^mD`AkBBMZ}@??SCB_@?Q?o@Ew@Ca@CWGa@GWG]Qi@IUUa@EMKQGIWiB??QJSg@{BuGcCaK??UNMa@aDcK]cC??UJK]iAkDGUE[MgARk@??YDkAsS??WDC_@KeAKuAK_AKc@q@{BSk@Fc@??QPS]S]kIgNiB}C}@}A_@_B??SRIKqBiD_BkCq@_Ag@o@k@k@w@eAS[uBmD{@yA[c@QS[]Mm@??GX]S_@Qm@WSEYKg@Mg@Gg@AkAAe@]???\\w@?oLi@??l@^m@ASAOAUAa@ISEa@Mu@Yq@]q@a@WQ][i@m@k@w@Q_@IM[_AQc@Ke@SgAGo@T[??YDE_@Aw@AgCAkDCuEXk@??Y?AaE?}A?wCVo@??W?A}AAmD?oFTkI??Wn@?o@?cE?{DAm@EmAC_@CWS{AGSOk@Yu@]}@Fi@??UPM[sDeH}BwE{@gBAw@??UPa@}@qB}Do@uA_@m@}@cB}AoC]aB??SPeAkBmA{Bq@gAaFcK??Bv@Wc@}B}DsC{EgAmBsA_CsDmGk@aAaCmE_@aB??SRGKOUKSoAoBaA{Aw@wAk@eAg@eA[}@iA}DB_A??WLmAcFaAqDkCkJwAmFDy@??UJeA_Eq@iCYgAqBmHgDeO???fAU{@uAgFsB}Hq@gCsB{Hi@sBB{@??UJUy@Mg@w@mC}AoG{@oDWgAF{@??UJ]yAQaA{@qEUmAi@cCUqAG[WmAK[Ia@Ma@g@qAOg@IYKa@Pe@??YJQ_Ak@uCk@gDUkAOs@?wA??WJOu@CIu@kD[aBw@{DOu@Rc@??YHIi@Im@MkAMiAO}ASsCEk@UcDC]Gq@@oG??WDCw@KoCCQKaCQcC_@{EWyCIkAEq@?sG??Ul@Ck@Au@UiI}@_i@??UbACaAa@yY??Ur@Aq@a@yM]yW??SbAEaAGoBKeCAeB@yAHmED_DKs@ISQUIGa@E{AC_@Em@|D@
```

[**Test the URL**](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=900x900&path=weight:5%7Ccolor:0x000000ff%7Cenc:mzxnEfswpUQVmCoCmAgAiDsD??GNUS_HqGeC%7DB%7BAuAy@u@oCcD??KPUSoBiBMMIG%7DEoEtBmC??SQNYP]jCuEhCuE%7BI%7BI??IL_@_@kF_FMIOOUSSUIG[WgB_BYWk@%7D@??IJ_A%7B@WWOOc@]BW@W@gAAq@C_C?e@@[Fo@@KBQJo@t@qA??WKDW%5EmB%60AaFVsAHc@RgAJc@Nw@Fc@rAcE??YKJo@z@qEbByGdCgJJc@BIRg@v@_Cn@cBX_AYcC??WLaBmFY%7B@q@qBO[i@sAUm@Se@IYuA_GBiA??WJyAiGmEwGeBgC[c@[mA??QTQWmDuEe@o@KM_@e@YkA??QTY_@w@aASsA??SRQ[s@wA%7B@wAeDaH??SPYa@mAoB_EcGcA%7DAGKe@s@S]OQ_@s@o@qA_@%7D@KYGoA??UNcAmCIsA??UNiA%7DCgBcFwBwH??UN_BeEQe@Wo@O[_@k@Y]KK%7B@u@W[aE_ESOKKSo@??KXm@_@[WuK%7BGyBuB??KXq@_@aKgGmBkB??KXWOgBeAe@Su@u@g@e@k@g@KGMKq@a@UMa@G%7B@EqDM[CY?QESIOEc@SQKc@]g@e@k@kA??OXUSu@k@wBoBaByAiAmAyAyAeEuDg@e@[_@MOU]QYOW%7B@qBMYI[Li@??WLKe@Ga@I_@Gs@C[Ck@EqBAm@?sABw@FkBFy@Fm@Dq@T_B%5EmD%60AkBBMZ%7D@??SCB_@?Q?o@Ew@Ca@CWGa@GWG]Qi@IUUa@EMKQGIWiB??QJSg@%7BBuGcCaK??UNMa@aDcK]cC??UJK]iAkDGUE[MgARk@??YDkAsS??WDC_@KeAKuAK_AKc@q@%7BBSk@Fc@??QPS]S]kIgNiB%7DC%7D@%7DA_@_B??SRIKqBiD_BkCq@_Ag@o@k@k@w@eAS[uBmD%7B@yA[c@QS[]Mm@??GX]S_@Qm@WSEYKg@Mg@Gg@AkAAe@]???%5C%5Cw@?oLi@??l@%5Em@ASAOAUAa@ISEa@Mu@Yq@]q@a@WQ][i@m@k@w@Q_@IM[_AQc@Ke@SgAGo@T[??YDE_@Aw@AgCAkDCuEXk@??Y?AaE?%7DA?wCVo@??W?A%7DAAmD?oFTkI??Wn@?o@?cE?%7BDAm@EmAC_@CWS%7BAGSOk@Yu@]%7D@Fi@??UPM[sDeH%7DBwE%7B@gBAw@??UPa@%7D@qB%7DDo@uA_@m@%7D@cB%7DAoC]aB??SPeAkBmA%7BBq@gAaFcK??Bv@Wc@%7DB%7DDsC%7BEgAmBsA_CsDmGk@aAaCmE_@aB??SRGKOUKSoAoBaA%7BAw@wAk@eAg@eA[%7D@iA%7DDB_A??WLmAcFaAqDkCkJwAmFDy@??UJeA_Eq@iCYgAqBmHgDeO???fAU%7B@uAgFsB%7DHq@gCsB%7BHi@sBB%7B@??UJUy@Mg@w@mC%7DAoG%7B@oDWgAF%7B@??UJ]yAQaA%7B@qEUmAi@cCUqAG[WmAK[Ia@Ma@g@qAOg@IYKa@Pe@??YJQ_Ak@uCk@gDUkAOs@?wA??WJOu@CIu@kD[aBw@%7BDOu@Rc@??YHIi@Im@MkAMiAO%7DASsCEk@UcDC]Gq@@oG??WDCw@KoCCQKaCQcC_@%7BEWyCIkAEq@?sG??Ul@Ck@Au@UiI%7D@_i@??UbACaAa@yY??Ur@Aq@a@yM]yW??SbAEaAGoBKeCAeB@yAHmED_DKs@ISQUIGa@E%7BAC_@Em@%7CD@)

Comment: Got it, in fact I didn't realize that the polylineutility add the @ to create the map. Thanks!!!, is there a define number of characters that the polyline should have? By by should be a multiplier of a number? do you know how I will be able to know that it is missing something when I plot it? because at the end Google generate a map, but I will not be able to recognize if it is plotting something or not. Thanks!